# Keep head comment with YUICompressor

Tags: javascript, comments, minify, yui-compressor

I use PhpStorm and YUICompressor to minify my JavaScript.

The problem is, that my head comment will be removed during minifiying. It looks like this:

```
/**
 * Head Comment.
 * 
 * @author KittMedia
 * @copyright 2016 KittMedia
 */
```

I know that you can preserve a comment by using a `!`, but it doesn’t work here because of the second asterisk in line 1.

I tried: `/*!*`

Will be compiled to: `/*!*`

Even `/*! *` will be compiled to `/*! *`. So the exclamation mark won’t be removed.

Any idea how to keep this type of comment in the minified version of my JavaScript file so that the head comment looks like above?